# mysql - 500 tables with 100K-1M rows or 1 table with 50-500M rows

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb

I've read many similar posts, yet I don't understand what to choose.
From software perspective it is game leaderboard. One table for all leaderboards or 500 small tables, one for each game level?

I've tested both variants, and have found:

- 1 big table works slower (with all needed indexes created).
- 1 big table should be partitioned at least into 10 files for adequate speed.
- 500 small tables are not that convenient, but twice faster (50M big table vs 100K small table)
- 500 small tables don't need partitioning (I heard about some problems with it in mysql, maybe in MariaDB 10.0 that I use everything is fixed, but just in case)

The only problem here is possibly many opened tables at once. I didn't thougt it's a problem until read setup suggestions in phpMyAdmin, so now I doubt should I use that many tables?

Just in case here's schemas.
"small" table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `level0` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `score` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `score` (`score`),
  KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `leaderboard` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `level_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `score` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `level_no` (`level_no`),
  KEY `score` (`score`),
  KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`),
  KEY `lev_sc` (`level_no`,`score`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50100 PARTITION BY HASH (id)
PARTITIONS 10 */
```

Queries for ranking:

```
SELECT   COUNT(score) FROM level0  WHERE score > $current_score 
ORDER BY score desc

SELECT   COUNT(score) FROM leaderboard  WHERE 
level_no = 0 and score > $current_score ORDER BY score desc
```

**update**

I've learned about indexes and ended up with the following schema for big table (20M rows):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `leaderboard` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `level_no` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `score` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`level_no`,`user_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `score` (`score`),
  KEY `level_no_score` (`level_no`,`score`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and for small (100K rows, got from leaderboard where level_no=200):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `level20` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `score` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  KEY `score` (`score`),
  KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

shared table with long literal user ids:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `player_ids` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `store_user_id` char(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `store_user_id` (`store_user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

For tests I've used these queries:

```
SELECT   COUNT(*) AS rank FROM level20 lev   WHERE score > 
  (SELECT score FROM level20 lt INNER JOIN player_ids pids ON 
    pids.id = lt.user_id WHERE pids.store_user_id='3FGTOHQN6UMwXI47IiRRMf9WI777SSJ6A' );

  SELECT   COUNT(*) AS rank FROM leaderboard lev   WHERE level_no=20 and score > 
  (SELECT score FROM leaderboard lt INNER JOIN player_ids pids ON 
    pids.id = lt.user_id WHERE pids.store_user_id='3FGTOHQN6UMwXI47IiRRMf9WI777SSJ6A'  and level_no=20 ) ;
```

I like the idea of using one big table, yet, while I'm getting similar timings (~0,050 for small and ~0,065 for big) on both queries, explain still confuses me a little:
for small table

**type | key | key_len | ref | rows | extra**

> index;    score;  4;  (null); 50049;  Using where, Using index

and for big table:

> ref;  PRIMARY 2;  const;  164030; Using where

As you can see there are 3x less rows was scanned in the small table. Data in all tables are identical, level20 was filled with query:

```
INSERT INTO level20 (user_id, score, timestamp) SELECT user_id, score,
    timestamp FROM leaderboard WHERE level_no=20;
```

**another update**

Have experimented today with tables and found that changing int to medium int almost doesn't change the size of the table. Here's statistics after optimize (recreate+analyse):

```
#medium ints
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `leaderboard1` (
  `user_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `level_no` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `score` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`level_no`,`user_id`),
  KEY `score` (`score`),
  KEY `level_no_score` (`level_no`,`score`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


Data 628    Mb
Index   521.6   Mb
Total   1.1 Gb

#ints
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `leaderboard` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `level_no` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `score` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`level_no`),
  KEY `score` (`score`),
  KEY `level_no_score` (`level_no`,`score`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Data 670    Mb
Index   597.8Mb
Total   1.2 Gb
```

And my queries work almost the same way on both tables. I have a feeling that table with medium ints is better and I leave it, yet still a little bit confused.

Comment: Will now if you want to search through all the records you are in for one extra fun select statement...

Comment: Is it in any way relational? If not, consider something like MongoDB, another NoSQL or some other form of JSON storage will likely be faster than MySQL.

Comment: @DanWhite it relates to profiles table, user ids table (64 symbols each), statistics events table, GCM tables and others. Of course they can exist separately but I'd prefer all on one server. Moreover I don't know MongoDB. Maybe there is nosql table engine in MariaDB/mysql? Or nosql means completely another software platform?

Comment: @JoshuaByer yes, but the only place where I need all the tables at once is cron-launched cache task "select user_id, score from t0 order by score limit 50 union all .... select user_id, score from t500 order by score limit 50". But it's very fast and happens once per hour.

Comment: How did you decide that the large table needed to be partitioned?  Based on the structure and queries, partitioning like that won't help and probably slow down the queries.  The `level_no` index in the large table is redundant since there is also an index on `(level_no, score)`.  If rows are unique on level and user, you'd be better off using `(user_id)` and `(level_no, user_id)` as the primary keys on the small and large tables respectively.  Your timestamp columns should probably be unsigned, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your queries are a bit strange. Try this

```
SELECT   COUNT(*) 
  FROM   leaderboard
 WHERE   level_no = 0 and score > $current_score
```

Your ORDER BY here is pointless because this query can only return a single row: it's an aggregate query without any  `GROUP BY`.

Five hundred tables is a terrible idea. Your administration tasks will be quite unpleasant.

Also, partitioning your tables rarely helps query performance. In the case you've proposed, partitioning on `hash(id)`, will definitely wreck performance for the query you've shown; every query will have to read every partition.

Keep it simple. One table. When it gets reasonably big, use EXPLAIN to analyze your query performance, and consider adding appropriate compound indexes.

Don't create indexes you don't need. They slow down inserts and waste hard drive space.  Read this  http://use-the-index-luke.com/ .

**Edit**  MySQL is built for this sort of four-longword table with half a billion rows. You *will* get this working if you're patient and learn about indexing. Don't waste your irreplaceable time with hundreds of smaller tables or with partitioning.  More RAM may help, though.

The best thing for performance with InnoDB is making sure that all of your frequently used data fits in the buffer pool.  With your posted table structures, it looks like you'll need roughly 500MB of buffer pool space to keep all of the data in the buffer pool.

A better structure for the leaderboard table would be:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `leaderboard` (
  `user_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `level_no` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `score` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`level_no`,`user_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `score` (`score`),
  KEY `level_no_score` (`level_no`,`score`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Changes:

1. `timestamp` and `user_id` columns are `UNSIGNED`: expands range for user IDs, I assume you're not using negative time values and current unix timestamps are above the signed range.
2. The timestamp may be easier to use as a `TIMESTAMP` type: the `TIMESTAMP` uses 4 bytes like `INT` but is shown as a datetime.
3. Removed the `level_no` index: it is redundant with the `level_no_score` index since prefixes of indexes can be used instead of the whole thing.
4. List item

Using `(level_no, user_id)` as the primary key will help if you frequently use those columns in queries and removes an unneeded column (`id`).  InnoDB does implicitly create a primary key only if one is not explicitly defined, so creating the `id` column only to use as a primary key is a waste.

The "correct" primary index also depends on the data and access pattern.  What is unique in the table?  Is it really `level_no` and `user_id` or is it just user?  If it's just `user_id` that will probably be a better primary key.

Comment: yes, I see now order by is pointless, thank you. And - I tried to keep it simple, but 50M rows on VDS with 2GB Ram and 2x2.4Ghz xeon cores looks a little bit slow. When I split it into 500 parts it became faster. But ok, you've made me rethink architecture. I'll do experiments tomorrow and will write my results.

Comment: I've completed some testing and edited my question. Please take a look.

Comment: @G_Nugget, thanks for clarification, my result is almost the same, unsigned int is better, but signed is enough too. Yes, (level_no, user_id) is unique, so it's the best PK.

Answer (score 1):

To save space (hence make things more cacheable, hence faster), shrink from INT (4 bytes) to MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED (3 bytes, 0-16M range) or smaller.

`CHAR(64)` -- are the strings always 64 characters?  If not, use `VARCHAR(64)` to save space.  ('3FGTOHQN6UMwXI47IiRRMf9WI777SSJ6A' is only 33?)

For `leaderboard`, I think you can get rid of one index:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `level_no`),  -- reversed
# KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),  -- not needed
KEY `score` (`score`),
KEY `level_no_score` (`level_no`,`score`)  -- takes care of any lookup by just `level_no`
```

Re "3x": "Rows" in `EXPLAIN` is an estimate.  Sometimes it is a crude estimate.

You know SQL; why go to the effort to code "SELECT" yourself for NoSQL?

PARTITIONing does not automatically provide *any* performance boost.  And you have not shown any queries that would benefit.

I agree that 500 similar tables is more trouble than it is worth.

2GB of RAM?  Better keep innodb_buffer_pool_size down at maybe 300M.  Swapping is *much* worse than shrinking the buffer_pool.

`leaderboard` PK -- You are saying that one `user_id` can be in multiple `levels`?

Comment: 0. I 'd prefer not to limit with 16m users -  just in case. thanks for index suggestions, I will test it.   1. as I read char works faster than varchar and it's more "convenient"  to DB.  some ids on WP8 for example would be longer  than 33 symbols. 2. I think  that  nosql is not for me. or what do you mean?   3. yes, I refused from partitioning and from small tables.  4. mysql and others recommend to set innodb_buffer_pool_size to70-80% of memory, so i set it to 1,4gb. why 300m? 5. in the table there are 200-500 rows for each user, that is why I moved user ids in separate table.

Comment: It's an old wives tale that `CHAR` is better than `VARCHAR`; erase that from your mind.  `CHAR(64)` (and latin1) occupies 64 bytes; `VARCHAR(...)` with only 33 chars occupies 35 bytes.  Smaller -> faster.

Comment: The 70%-80% recommendation is for modern-sized machines (> 4GB), _not_ for an  2GB virtual machine.  Other things (the Operating System, mysqld code, other buffers, etc, etc) takes a bunch of room, possibly 1GB.  When the total exceeds 2GB, "swapping" occurs.  Swapping is _much_ worse for performance than having a smaller buffer_pool.

Comment: 500 rows is a "tiny" table.  In one study, 20% of tables had more than a _million_ rows each.  Databases are designed for 'big'.  I have seen a few tables with over a billion rows.  _They_ have challenges.  164030 rows weighs in at about the 70th percentile, and needs some careful attention -- indexes and minimizing size.

Comment: I  mean 500 for each player,  for 100k it's 50m rows total. and in player ids table 100 k rows

Comment: regarding to memory - my vds works via kvm,  hardware virtualization,  so I've been told that I have exclusive access to 2gb of physical memory and 2 physical cores and shared access to ssd raid.  so it's almost real I suppose.    do you recommend 300mb anyway?  how to synthetically estimate where swapping begins?

Comment: I agree the smaller the faster but what 's about mysql docs statement that variable types always slower than const length and harder to restore corrupted table? at least it takes more time as each row has different size

Comment: Do you have a link to those quotes?  I would like to file a bug report against the docs.  It is _probably_ referring _only_ to MyISAM, and probably dates back nearly 20 years.  For a _small_ MyISAM table, where you do a lot of deletes and inserts, there is an advantage to having the entire table fixed length.  But any var destroys the advantage; you should use InnoDB; and for bigger tables I/O is usually more important.

Comment: Sure, you have _exclusive_ access to the 2GB.  But it is not just MySQL data, it is also mysql code, etc.  The code eats a big _fixed-size_ chunk.  When they provisioned the VM for you, didn't they offer you a choice of OS?  I believe the OS takes another _fixed-size_ chunk of the 2GB.  70% of _available_ ram is not much.  You could experiment by increasing the buffer_pool to 3G to force swapping; see what happens.

Comment: sounds reasonable, thanks for both remarks! I'll update my post just to show strange experiment results.

Comment: `INT` -> `MEDIUMINT` -- Yes, only 1 byte saved in data.  But, because the `PRIMARY KEY` is implicitly tacked onto each secondary key, you saved more in the index space.  However, due to RAM size and table size, the shrinkage is somewhat useful.  What part is "strange"?

Comment: yes, my bad. expected 75% reduce :) armed with calc see now everything is as expected